# Issue while triggering jenkins pipeline using github webhooks for specific branch

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, git-webhooks

Trying to trigger Jenkins pipeline using Github webhooks for a specific branch. Pipeline should trigger for a merge commit but having an issue in triggering. Tried it using 'Generic Webhook Trigger' plugin.

If I use ^(refs/heads/release-1.0)$ in optional filters and pipeline is triggering whenever something is merged into release-1.0 branch and pipeline build is successful

But when i used ^(refs/heads/release-*)$ in optional filters, the pipeline is not triggering. 
Here why I am using release-* is release branches have tag numbers. For example: release-1.0, release-1.1, release-1.2 and so on.

Can anyone help me with this question.

Answer (score 1):

This `^(refs/heads/release-)$` is a regexp, starting (`^`) with, end ending (`$`), enclosing specifc text `refs/heads/release-` .

You need to extend the regexp pattern match, eg: `.*` or `[0-9]*\.[0-9]*`, here: `release-{here}`

From [README.md](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README.md),

This [regexp](https://jex.im/regulex/) site Also syntax [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)